# Rails custom route form_for error: param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I am getting this error: `param is missing or the value is empty: character`. I am baffled. There must be a problem with form_for somewhere, but I just can't find it. I'm updating `Character` attributes in the `Users` controller but that shouldn't matter I think?

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"_method"=>"patch",
"authenticity_token"=>"...",
"picturethings"=>{"picture"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001100087f8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/19/_vdcl1r913g6fzvk1l56x4km0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150524-4855-1eieu5j.jpeg>,
@original_filename="GOT1.jpeg",
@content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picturethings[picture][]\"; filename=\"GOT1.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]},
"commit"=>"Upload pictures",
"callsign"=>"bazzer"}
```

views/users/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @character, url: update_pictures_user_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :picturethings, html: { multipart: true } do |p| %>
    <%= p.label :picture %>
    <%= p.file_field :picture, multiple: true, name: "picturethings[picture][]" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload pictures" %>
<% end %>
```

users_controller.rb

```
def edit
  @character = Character.find_by(callsign: params[:callsign])
  @user = @character.sociable
  @picturething = @character.picturethings.build
end

def update_pictures
  @character = Character.find_by(callsign: params[:callsign])
  if @character.update_attributes(update_pictures_user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Pictures updated"
    params[:picturethings]['picture'].each do |p|
      @picturething = @character.picturethings.create!(picture: p, character_id: @character.id)
    end
    render 'edit'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def update_pictures_user_params
  params.require(:character).permit(picturethings_attributes: [:picture])
end
```

character.rb

```
belongs_to :sociable, polymorphic: true
has_many :picturethings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :picturethings
```

user.rb

```
has_one  :character, as: :sociable, dependent: :destroy
```

routes.rb

```
patch '/users/:callsign/update_pictures', to: 'users#update_pictures', as: :update_pictures_user
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file input name is incorrect. If you look at the form data:

```
form-data; name=\"picturethings[picture][]\"; filename=\"GOT1.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
```

There is no `character` param.

The correct name attribute would look something like this:

```
character[picturethings_attributes][1][picture][]
```

When Rails parses the form data it will convert it into the following hash:

```
character: {
  picturethings_attributes: {
    0 => {
      picture : [] # an array of files.
    }
  }
}
```

You don't need to specify the name manually:

```
<%= form_for @character, url: update_pictures_user_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :picturethings, html: { multipart: true } do |p| %>
    <%= p.label :picture %>
    <%= p.file_field :picture, multiple: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload pictures" %>
<% end %>
```

Rails will give you the correct name attribute. You also don't need to manually create the associated records - that's the whole point of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
def update_pictures
  @character = Character.find_by(callsign: params[:callsign])
  if @character.update_attributes(update_pictures_user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Pictures updated"
    render 'edit'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you papirtiger, I made the changes you suggested and I now have a character parameter. However it has created a new problem: every time a file is uploaded and the edit page refreshes, more `.field` divs appear, so there are now about 100 `p.file_field` buttons on the page. I can't get rid of them. The character seems to have 100 `picturethings`. But only a few of them have corresponding `pictures` (I added `<% @character.picturethings.each do |picturething| %>
        <%= image_tag picturething.picture %>` to display the pictures). I may have to start a new question for this.

Comment: Start a new question please.

Comment: [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445740/rails-unwanted-instances-appearing-in-view-and-being-saved-to-the-database)