# Rails: unwanted instances appearing in view and being saved to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

File upload is handled on the `users/edit.html.erb` page. Every time a file is uploaded and the edit page refreshes, more `<div class="field">` divs appear, doubling the number of `p.file_field` buttons on the page each time. It seems what is happening is caused by `@picturething = @character.picturethings.build` in the edit action of the users controller. Previous instances of `@picturething` are kept in memory and displayed by `f.fields_for :picturethings`. So I end up with say 8 `<div class="field">` divs. When I use one of them to save a file to the database, 7 picturethings are saved to the database each with an empty `:picture`, along with the one picturething which is saved to the database with a `:picture`. So next time there are 16 `<div class="field">` divs on the page. I've never seen this behaviour before with `.build`. How do I correct it?

**users_controller.rb**

```
def edit
  @character = Character.find_by(callsign: params[:callsign])
  @user = @character.sociable
  @picturething = @character.picturethings.build
end

def update_pictures
  @character = Character.find_by(callsign: params[:callsign])
  @user = @character.sociable
  if @character.update_attributes(update_pictures_user_params)
    redirect_to(edit_user_path(@user))
  else
    redirect_to(edit_user_path(@user))
  end
end

def update_pictures_user_params
  params.require(:character).permit({picturethings_attributes: :picture})
end
```

**views/users/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @character, url: update_pictures_user_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :picturethings, html: { multipart: true } do |p| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= p.label :picture %>
      <%= p.file_field :picture %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload pictures" %>
<% end %>

<% @character.picturethings.each do |picturething| %>
  <%= image_tag picturething.picture %>
<% end %>
```

**character.rb**

```
has_many :picturethings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :picturethings
```

**user.rb**

```
has_one :character, as: :sociable, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :character
```

**picturething.rb**

```
belongs_to :character
mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
```

**routes.rb**

```
patch '/users/:callsign/update_pictures', to: 'users#update_pictures',  as: :update_pictures_user
```

**Parameters**
(when submitting a new file after many `<div class="field">` have appeared)

```
"utf8"=>"✓",
authenticity_token"=>"...",
"character"=>{
  "picturethings_attributes"=>{
    "0"=>{
      "picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000010be0e2a8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/19/_vdcl1r913g6fzvk1l56x4km0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150525-4855-cwpwrk.jpeg>, @original_filename="GOT1.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"character[picturethings_attributes][0][picture]\"; filename=\"GOT1.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "id"=>"1"}, 
      "1"=>{"id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"3"}, "3"=>{"id"=>"4"}, "4"=>{"id"=>"5"}, "5"=>{"id"=>"6"}, "6"=>{"id"=>"7"}, "7"=>{"id"=>"8"}, "8"=>{"id"=>"9"}, "9"=>{"id"=>"10"}, "10"=>{"id"=>"11"}, "11"=>{"id"=>"12"}, "12"=>{"id"=>"13"}, "13"=>{"id"=>"14"}, "14"=>{"id"=>"15"}, "15"=>{"id"=>"16"}
    }
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Upload pictures", 
  "callsign"=>"bazzer"
}
```

Comment: I would drop the `fields_for` and just incorporate everything in the `form_for`.  That looks the most fishy to me (unless you are squirreling away some bizarro `jQuery` you are not telling us about).

Comment: Something like `<%= form_for @character.picturethings, url: update_pictures_user_path, html: { multipart: true } do |p| %>`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked:
`<%= form_for @picturething, url: update_pictures_user_path, method: :patch, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>`
(it wouldn't accept `@character.picturethings` because it is a collection)

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you are saving blank fields to the database. You can do some validation in `character.rb`:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :picturething, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:picture].blank? }
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I thought about trying this, I might be wrong but I felt it would have covered up a deeper flaw somewhere. The simple approach solution by steve klein is the way I went in the end.